# Tomcat throw 401 when use curl do HTTPS upload

Tags: tomcat, curl, https, http-status-code-401, digest

Help!

We have a web server which use tomcat 7, client use curl(7.19.7), use curl do HTTPS upload file, in most cases, the file can be uploaded to web server successfully, but in few cases, the upload will fail, get 401 error, see below error from local access log, any one can help this? Thanks much.

> 10.155.60.75 - - [01/Aug/2013:09:38:27 +0800] POST /hm/upload?FileType=7&ApNodeId=4018B1208720 HTTP/1.1 401 954 0.001
>
> 10.155.60.75 - - [01/Aug/2013:09:38:27 +0800] POST /hm/upload?FileType=7&ApNodeId=4018B1208720 HTTP/1.1 401 954 0.001

if succeeded, we will got one 401, one 200, see below,

> 10.155.60.75 - - [01/Aug/2013:09:39:31 +0800] POST /hm/upload?FileType=7&ApNodeId=4018B1208720 HTTP/1.1 401 954 0.000
>
> 10.155.60.75 - scpuser [01/Aug/2013:09:39:32 +0800] POST /hm/upload?FileType=7&ApNodeId=4018B1208720 HTTP/1.1 200 - 0.063

Comment: I don't understand why two requests are made to upload a single file, but I don't know how curl works, so it may be perfectly fine.

Comment: it's not upload a single file, but another new file, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your kind revised work.